# How to configure EXM to create new messages with a custom language version, as default

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-ecm, sitecore-exm

I am trying to configure the EXM root for an Austrian website to create the new messages with a de-AT language version and to have the **de-AT** language selected as default.

**My question is:** How can I configure EXM to automatically create a language version for de-AT when a new message is created?

**What I've done so far ..**

I managed to achieve having the de-AT selected automatically by playing around with the ***Language - Select the target language*** field from the *Message Context* section of the **Standard fields** - but the actual message item that is created does not contain the de-AT version - and I am getting an error when trying to save the message.

[image]

**Error message:** *Edited language version 'German (Austria)' could not be found. It may have been deleted by another user.*

As it can be seen in this screnshot, when I open EXM and I create a new message, the de-AT language version is automatically selected. The problem is that the message has no de-AT language version assigned, so it won't allow to save the item.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to only work correctly when changing the Default Content Language to that specific Language in the User Manager. The `shell` `contentLanguage` attribute is ignored. I'm submitting a ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to add language version to standard values of your message template.[image: message version]

Templates in EXM works in a same way as anywhere in Sitecore. You should have language versions for your emails under:

- /sitecore/templates/Email Campaign/Messages
- /sitecore/templates/Branches/Email Campaign/Messages

Comment: Thank you for the answer Anton. I did try that as well, before posting the question. Nothing seems to be able to create a de-AT language version. Added the version to __StandardValues, branch templates .. no result

Comment: I am going to plug-in a new pipeline in EXM configs, when the method "OnItemAdded" is triggered, to create a custom language version for my messages

Answer (score 0):

None of the 'tricks' worked to automatically add a new language version when you create a new message inside EXM, therefore I've added a new `OnItemSave` event which checks if the Item is derived from the base Message template and creates a new language version - based on the own business logic.

**Config:**

```
<configuration xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore> 
 <events>
  <event name="item:added"> 
    <handler type="ABC.SitecoreExtensions.Handlers.EmailExperienceExtensions, ABC" method="OnItemAdded" />
  </event> 
</events> 
</sitecore>
```

**Code**

```
namespace ABC.SitecoreExtensions.Handlers
{
  class EmailExperienceExtensions
  {
    readonly Sitecore.Data.Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master"); 
    private const string EXM_BASE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID = "{A0EA9681-5C86-43AB-80F7-C522DADF6F12}";


    public void OnItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
        Item obj1 = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
        if (obj1 == null)
            return;

        if (obj1.IsDerived(new Sitecore.Data.ID(EXM_BASE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID )))
        {
            //logic to determine the context site and to pickup the language
            ....

            if (rootItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var siteContext = SiteContext.GetSite(rootItem.Name);
            var lang = LanguageManager.GetLanguage(siteContext.Language);

            Item ca = masterDb.GetItem(obj1.Paths.FullPath, lang);
            using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (0 == ca.Versions.Count)
                    {
                        ca.Versions.AddVersion();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   // catch exception
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

}